# WP 3.1 meta_query for multiple custom field values

Tags: custom-field, customization, meta-query

I'm trying to use some conditional logic to compare custom fields in my query, but a bit stuck. How would I get all posts with ReleasedProject AND PermanentArtist set to 'true'?

Here's what I have so far, I'm assuming it's something to do with 'compare':

Thanks

osu

**EDIT**: To clarify what I want to do - I'm trying to exclude pages that have two custom field values (ReleasedProject and PermanentArtist in this case) set to 'false'. These are set through checkboxes generated using the plugin Custom Field Template.

I've updated the code to illustrate that I need to filter out all pages with these two custom fields set to false:

```
global $post;
$artist_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'ReleasedProject',
            'value' => 'false'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'PermanentArtist',
            'value' => 'false'
        )
    )
);
$my_query = new WP_Query($artist_args);
```

Comment: I cannot see any problem with that query and should work as you have asked.

Comment: This is a bit confusing, do you want to compare the 2 meta box values with each other or do you just want to query and display them if they contain a value ( not compare them).

Comment: Have you done a `print_r($my_query)` to see if anything is returned? Try doing this without `meta_query` and see if any pages are returned...

Comment: @Brady @Wyck - I've updated the code and added a note to show what I'm doing, is that any clearer?

Comment: You say you want to exclude posts but you show code with `'post_type' => 'page',`. You are aware you have this set to page and not post

Comment: Plus all you have done is change the logic with your edit... before you said you want to only show posts that have `ReleasedProject` AND `PermanentArtist` set to `true`. Now you want to exclude posts that have `ReleasedProject` AND `PermanentArtist` set to `false`. They are completly different logic... So which one do you want?

Comment: @Brady - my bad, meant to say 'pages'. But I'm trying to understand the logic so I can use both examples (both set to true and both set to false). The problem I'm having at the moment is that setting both ´ReleasedProject´ AND ´PermanentArtist´ to false shows nothing while there are pages that don't have both these custom fields set to true. I'm trying to get at those ones (essentially excluding the ones set to true). Any ideas?

Comment: For anyone that needs help with this, to exclude posts with a certain custom field value, you can filter the results within the while loop by doing this: http://www.pastie.org/1887833

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all posts that have `ReleasedProject` AND `PermanentArtist` both set to true, you need to change the `value` keys for both of those to `'true'`. If you want to exclude all posts that have both of those set to `'false'`, you need to add `'compare' => '!='` to both meta query arrays.

### EDIT

The logic behind meta queries is such that all conditions must be met (it's an `AND` relationship). So if you say

```
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'ReleasedProject',
        'value' => 'false'
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'PermanentArtist',
        'value' => 'false'
    )
)
```

That means "find all posts that have both Released Project identical to `'false'` AND Permanent Artist identical to `'false'`." If you were to add the `'compare' => '!='` statement like I mentioned earlier, it would be saying "find all posts that have both Released Project NOT identical to `'false'` AND Permanent Artist NOT identical to `'false'`." If you have a post that has Released Project set to `'false'` and Permanent artist set to `'true'`, it will not show up in either of those queries.

Furthermore, if a meta value is missing, it will not show up in the results either. So if you have a post with Released project set to true, and permanent artist not set at all, this meta query will not find that post:

```
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'ReleasedProject',
        'value' => 'false',
        'compare' => '!='
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'PermanentArtist',
        'value' => 'false'
        'compare' => '!='
    )
)
```

Basically, meta queries don't do 'either/or' checks, they do 'both/and' checks when you have multiple meta queries.

Comment: thanks for this, I tried this, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. Here are some examples of what happens: 1) http://pastie.org/1886125 (this shows nothing) 2) http://pastie.org/1886132 (this shows pages with custom field ´ReleasedProject´ 3) http://pastie.org/1886135 (this shows nothing). So, it seems I'm having issues trying to get ´meta_query´ to work with two custom fields. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you absolutely positive that you have posts that have both meta values set to `'true'`? I'll update my answer with an explanation of the logic.

Comment: that's a good explanation. After a nights sleep and reading your answer, I realised that pages being filtered by `meta_query` would show nothing as each page has either `ReleasedProject` OR `PermanentArtist` set to false, not both within one page. Thanks for your help!